# Do 2 processes at a time. 1)find command 2)if-else condition depending on command line argument, it does not enter elif condition at all.Why?

Tags: bash, shell

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} &&
count=$2

if [[ "$count" -eq 0 ]] ;then

    echo "there are 0 .mov files in this path"

elif [[ "$count" -eq 1 ]] ;then

    echo "there is 1 .mov file in this path"

elif [[ $1 = "arg1" ]] ; then

    echo "arg1 "

elif [[ "$1" == "arg2" ]] || [[ "$1" == "arg10" ]] ; then

    echo "arg2 or arg10 "

else

echo "else"

fi

#)' ';'
```

I am trying to enter all subdirectories and trying to do a process using if-else condition.
If first and last lines are commented script works fine. otherwise script never enters arg1 elif condition, or arg2 elif condition but enters else part. Why?

Comment: How does the quoted shell command get its  `$2`?

Comment: which are the value of $1 and $2 ? I guess that $1 should be the value of find result

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are using Bash constructs like `[[` in a script snippet which you are passng to `sh`. But it is extremely unclear what you want the script to actually accomplish, and you have not responded to requests for clarification. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: See also now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548088/not-entering-if-condition-when-using-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
#!/bin/bash


find . -name "test*" -type d -exec bash -c '( cd {} &&
par1=$1
count=$2
echo "count [$count] - par1[$par1]"

if [[ $count -eq 0 ]];then

    echo "there are 0 .mov files in this path"

elif [[ $count -eq 1 ]];then

    echo "there is 1 .mov file in this path"

elif [[ "${par1}" == "arg1" ]];then

    echo "arg1"

elif [[ "${par1}" == "arg2" ]] || [[ "$1" == "arg10" ]];then

    echo "arg2 or arg10 "

else

echo "else"

fi

)' bash $1 $2 {} \;
```

try to explain:

1) assuming that the `$1` and `$2` are external parameter, they must be passed to the script before to be assigned in variables so, at the end of the script add:

`bash $1 $2 {} \;`

2) then assign variables:

```
par1=$1
count=$2
```

2) to verify string you must use `==` i.e. `[[ "${par1}" == "arg2" ]]`

3) to verify number `"`are not needed `[[ $count -eq 0 ]]`

4) as you can see I've used `find . -name "test*"` and I've created two directories `test1` `test2`

output:

```
[myShell] ➤ ./i arg1 0
count [0] - par1[arg1]
there are 0 .mov files in this path
count [0] - par1[arg1]
there are 0 .mov files in this path

[myShell] ➤ ./i arg1 1
count [1] - par1[arg1]
there is 1 .mov file in this path
count [1] - par1[arg1]
there is 1 .mov file in this path


[myShell] ➤ ./i arg1 2
count [2] - par1[arg1]
arg1
count [2] - par1[arg1]
arg1

[myShell ➤ ./i arg2 2
count [2] - par1[arg2]
arg2 or arg10
count [2] - par1[arg2]
arg2 or arg10
```

instead, if you don't need to use input as paramter but as internal variable you can do it like this and use $3 as the result of find command

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=arg1
var2=2

find . -name "test*" -type d -exec bash -c '( cd {} &&
par1=$1
count=$2
echo "count [$count] - par1[$par1] - directory[$3]"

if [[ $count -eq 0 ]];then

    echo "there are 0 .mov files in this path"

elif [[ $count -eq 1 ]];then

    echo "there is 1 .mov file in this path"

elif [[ "${par1}" == "arg1" ]];then

    echo "arg1"

elif [[ "${par1}" == "arg2" ]] || [[ "$1" == "arg10" ]];then

    echo "arg2 or arg10 "

else

echo "else"

fi

)' bash $var1 $var2 {} \;
```

output

```
[myShell] ➤ ./i
count [2] - par1[arg1] - directory[./test1]
arg1
count [2] - par1[arg1] - directory[./test2]
arg1
```

Comment: The subshell in the `sh -c` is useless and you should double-quote all filename variables and user-supplied variables.