# not entering if condition when using a function

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

function func_name {

arg1=$1; arg2=$2; 

if [[ "${arg1}" == "abcd" ]]; then
    echo enterd abcd condition
else
    echo entered else
fi

}

export -f func_name

find . -name "*" -type d -exec bash -c '( cd {} &&

func_name;

)' bash $1 $2 {} \;
```

Trying to run a function having if condition as a subshell inside find statement. It just enters else part. Why?

Comment: You never answered requests for clarification in [this previous question of yours](//stackoverflow.com/questions/36493277/do-2-processes-at-a-time-1find-command-2if-else-condition-depending-on-comman) and now you have another question with the same problem. We cannot read your mind, and code which doesn't do what you want only tells us what you don't want. You need to explain what you want to accomplish and how you think this code will take you there.

Comment: Note that the `-name '*'` is essentially a no-op; it reports on both hidden names beginning with `.` and those that are normally visible.

Comment: I marked one of the answers as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer by ClaudioM

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what arguments should be passed where, but your current attempt is certainly wrong. You aren't passing *any* arguments to `func_name` when you are calling it, so `"$arg1"` is expanding to the empty string. I suspect you want something like

```
find . -name "*" -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$1" && func_name "$2" "$3"' {} "$1" "$2" \;
```

Here, `func_name` is explicitly given the arguments passed to the original script. You don't need the subshell in the argument to `-c`, since the entire command is already run in a separate process.

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you probably don't actually need to use `find`.

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do
    pushd "$d"
    func_name "$1" "$2"
    pops
done
```

Comment: That much is clear, but how exactly do you want and expect them to be passed to the subshell, and on to the function?

Comment: I wanted the command-line arguments even to be read by the function. However chepner's solution for basah 4 or later works fine. But I did not get the right meaning of find statement solution given by him

Comment: `$1` et al inside the function refer to the *function's* arguments, not the script's arguments. You have to pass them explicitly, first to the shell that `find` runs, then to the function itself.

Comment: In 3 positions "$" is used. Could you explain ?

Comment: That is basic [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside a function block are only evaluated when the function is called. If you want to bind some variables at function declaration time, use `eval`, or a pair of global variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

_private_foo=$1
_private_bar=$2

func_name {
  if [[ "$_private_foo" == "abcd" ]]; then
    echo entered abcd condition
  else
    echo entered else
  fi
}
```

If subsequent code never changes the global variables `_private_foo` and `_private_bar`, the function will work as if the initial global values of `$1` and `$2` were interpolated into the function definition, without the myriad complications and perils of `eval`.

If you need the function to work in a subshell, you'll need to also `export` the globals, or somehow otherwise pass them in, as pointed out by @chepner.

Comment: You'll have to export `_private_foo` and `_private_bar`, though, if `func_name` is called by a shell started by `find`, since the shell uses dynamic scope.